# How to check if a visited node is in if part or else part of IfStatement node in Eclipse JDT parsing?

Tags: eclipse, location, eclipse-jdt

When I visit a MethodInvocation node during AST traversal, I want to know if it lies in the IfStatement *then*  part or *else* part or in the *expression* part. The *then* part can be a complete block of code but I think my code is handling only a single then statement.

Here is the code snippet for visiting a method invocation

```
@Override
    public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) 
    {           
        StructuralPropertyDescriptor location = node.getLocationInParent();
        setNodeRegion(location);
```

Here is how I want to set flags for each region of IfStatement

```
 private void setNodeRegion(StructuralPropertyDescriptor location) {
        if(location == IfStatement.EXPRESSION_PROPERTY ||
                location == IfStatement.THEN_STATEMENT_PROPERTY)
        {
            ParseContextAction.ifBlockRegion = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(location == IfStatement.ELSE_STATEMENT_PROPERTY)
            {
                ParseContextAction.elseBlockRegion = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if(location == CatchClause.BODY_PROPERTY)
                {
                    ParseContextAction.catchBlockRegion = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ParseContextAction.basicBlockRegion = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another alternate question: Is it possible to visit the expression part, then part, and else part of an IfStatement separately to set flags?

Comment: Check if an ancestor of `node` (`node.getParent()`, `node.getParent().getParent()`, ...) is an instance of `IfStatement` which has `getThenStatement()` and `getElseStatement()`.

Comment: @howlger I had the same in mind, but recursively getting the parent part until an IfStatement is encountered or root node is reached, seems like an expensive solution.

Comment: You can also implement/override `visit(IfStatement node)` of the AST visitor which is called before `visit(MethodInvocation node)` which are contained in that _if_ statement.

Comment: Again "Would it be possible to visit the expression part, then part, and else part of an IfStatement separately to set flags?" An if statement has three parts and the then part and else part contain multiple statements. I want to determine if a specific method invocation lies in the then part or else part. Visiting the IfStatement node is of no use unless the parts of an if can be visited separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `visit(IfStatement node)` instead of `visit(MethodInvocation node)`, you can visit both the *then* (`getThenStatement()`) and the *else* (`getElseStatement()`) branch with a separate visitor:

```java
@Override
public boolean visit(IfStatement node) {

    Statement thenBranch = node.getThenStatement(); 
    if (thenBranch != null) {
        thenBranch.accept(new ASTVisitor(false) {
            @Override
            public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
                // handle method invocation in the then branch
                return true; // false, if nested method invocations should be ignored
            }
        }
    }

    Statement elseBranch = node.getElseStatement(); 
    if (elseBranch != null) {
        elseBranch.accept(new ASTVisitor(false) {
            @Override
            public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
                // handle method invocation in the else branch
                return true; // false, if nested method invocations should be ignored
            }
        }
    }

    return true; // false, if nested if statements should be ignored
}
```