# why do we need to build java code before importing to eclipse for methods autosuggestion

Tags: java, eclipse, build, ide, development-environment

I have a fundamental question, but something which bothers me a lot. We sync code from perforce in my company. and then we are taught to build the code compatible to eclipse. Then we import the code in eclipse as existing project. Then when we hit ctrl-space from an object, we get suggestions of methods.

My question is: Why do we need to build the code for suggestions of methods? . After syncing from perforce, what I have is still an existing java project (right?). So eclipse should be smart enough to be able to index and find out from source code, the methods, when I hit ctrl-space on an object?.

Why do I need to build? What purpose the build serves?

Comment: thanks duffymo for an alternative. But since eclipse is also used widely (from what I know), this question arises.

Comment: Eclipse is perfectly capable of doing suggestions without any 'build'. In fact it is probably ignoring the build and compiling the code itself anyway.

Comment: greg, In my setup eclipse doesn't build code. I don't import all informatica related dependencies. I build from command line.

Comment: Of course Eclipse builds and runs code.

Comment: This is probably a question better asked of one of your coworkers. Eclipse can do this for you, and it may be turned off (automatic builds). There was likely a bug somewhere at sometime and someone in your org came up with this workaround. It's been passed down from generation to generation of employees and in a few more years, no-one will have any idea of why this was done a la [The Roast Joke](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/grandmas-cooking-secret/).

Comment: @JasonArmstrong : I asked a few colleagues (may be I should ask some more senior people), and having to need build was obvious to everyone. Perhaps, I couldn't articulate well to them. I don't understand, why is this BUILD coming into picture at all. I feel, eclipse should be able to make index/some kind of data structure and be able to suggest method names.

Comment: This is likely an organizational problem, and not a technical one. Eclipse can do what you're asking. The only other thing is if the build process does byte code enhancement, source code generation or some other shenanigans that haven't been wired into your Eclipse build process.  I would argue that this is still an organizational problem because Eclipse can do that too; someone just may never have set it up or documented how to set it up for your app.

Comment: I enabled "build automatically". Even then method suggestions are not showing up with object. (I have not followed taught procedure i.e. building from informatica customized mvn command line, then importing as existing project)

Comment: @JasonArmstrong : thanks for insight!

Comment: Based on that last comment about Informatica customized mvn command line, I'm going to guess that's the culprit. That build process is generating some code.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong : okay. will check with colleagues again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **code does not have to be built**, but to be able to import a directory as project via ***File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace*** into Eclipse, at least the file **`.project` must exist**.

There are several ways to import, for example, a Maven project:

- Execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the command line and in Eclipse do *File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace*
- *File > Import...: Maven > Existing Maven Projects* without a command line call uses by default the in Eclipse embedded Maven
- ***File > Open Projects from File System...*** (or in *Git Repositories* view right-click + *Import Projects...*) detects not only Maven projects but also plain Java projects and automatically configures them accordingly.

In all three ways the following files are created, which are required in Eclipse for the Java content assist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) to work:

- `.project` - says whether it is e. g. a Java, a PHP or a C/C++ project (to be more precise, the project name, builders and natures are specified here, e. g. the project folder icon of a Java Maven project will be decorated with a `M` and a `J` based on the Java and Maven project natures)
- `.classpath` - tells Eclipse where the source and output folders are and which JARs should be added to the classpath (in Maven projects, the JARs are not listed, but it refers to the Maven dependencies which are computed from the `pom.xml` file)
- `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` - contains Java compiler and optional formatter settings (e. g. which Java version; which problems should be ignored or shown as infos, as warnings or as errors, etc.)

With [Eclipse Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph) you can automate even more: you select a project and based on a project-specific configuration, for example, a Git repository is automatically cloned and plug-ins necessary to edit the project are automatically installed and configured.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. I don't find any "File > Open Projects from File System" option.

Comment: "Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)"

Comment: @BioLogic Eclipse Mars is too old (released 3 years ago), the so-called [_Smart Import_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import) has been introduced two years ago. Please upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

Eclipse uses relfection for the suggestion, it can be possible only if the .class file generated

Comment: could you please provide some links as well. Found https://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial

Comment: No, Eclipse does not use relfection for code completion. Eclipse has its own compiler that contains a parser to build an abstract syntax tree (AST) (see e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488920/6505250). The suggestions are made based on the AST. An (incomplete) AST can even be built if there are compiler errors. That wouldn't work with reflection.

Comment: @howlger : Then why do I need to build the code from command line (with some eclipse flag set) and then import into eclipse and then be able to see methods suggestions with an object?? Am I doing this unnecessarily or everyone has to do this step?

Comment: To import e. g. a Maven project you can run Maven from the command line to create project settings files that are required by Eclipse (e. g. `.project` and `.classpath`) based on the `pom.xml` file. I prefer to use _File > Open Projects from File System..._ (or in the _Git Repositories_ view _Import Projects..._) instead which does the same.

Comment: @howlger : At the cost of sounding totally ignorant, what exactly is present in .project file, which is needed by eclipse to suggest method names?

Comment: The `.project` file says what natures (and project builders) the project has, e. g. for example that it is a Java, PHP or C/C++ project. For Java projects also the file `.classpath` is required which tells Eclipse where the source folders are and which JARs are present in the classpath. The Java compiler settings are stored in `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`.